# WPF Animation: can't bind From property to the ActualWidth

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls, wpf-animation

I'm trying to change a selected TabItem's width in the following way:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                                                     From="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                                                     To="200" 
                                                     Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I'm forced to specify the "From" property for the animation because I don't specify the "Width" property for the TabItem explicitly, it is calculated by the custom layout container. 
But when I try to bind "From" property of the animation to the "ActualWidth" property of the TabItem, the initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem' threws an exception. I tried to move the "Triggers" section inside the "ControlTemplate" section, but with no effect. So I have 2 questions:

1) Why can't the "From" property be bound to the ActualWidth of the TabItem in the way I did it?

2) How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Without specifying the `From`, How does it behaves?

Comment: @Sankarann, it throws an exception " Cannot animate the 'Width' property on a 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem' using a 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'".

Comment: Hard coding some value in from, is works fine?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine.

Comment: @Sankarann, though animation doesn't throw an exception now, its behaviour isn't desired, now it sets a width of the TabItem = From at the beginning of the animation, and changes it to To, it doesn't start at the actual width of the TabItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done because WPF framework will freeze the things which would used for the Animation by initially and So if you are trying to Bind on a [Freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx), it doest accept that. That's why it was prevented from changing and says,

*Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads*